# Why is my Photoshop 3D extrusion not working as expected?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photoshop-effects

I am trying to make this rectangle 3D with the same color for the extrusion.
[image: The original rectangle]

But I am getting this result instead:
[image: The result]

Notice that the rectangle seems to appear again in a smaller size, instead of filling the front and the extrusion with this color.
Any help would be appreciated.
Thank you

The steps I take:
[image: GIF demonstration]

1. I create a rectangle in PS (no stroke)
2. Right click on the layer
3. Select New 3D Extrusion From Selected Layer

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. I can't really reproduce this issue.  Do you perhaps have a thick stroke set on the rectangle?  It's all I can really think of.  
Can you share the exact steps you used to create it?

Comment: @BillyKerr I updated the question with a demo. It looks like instead of applying the rectangle as texture, it applies the whole page as texture or something like that. I tried with pixel layer, smart object layer copied from AI, and the result is the same.